# How are deterministic/logical nodes represented mathematically in directed graphical models?

Tags: sampling, graphical-model, bugs

Various software for performing inference on graphical models support logical(a.k.a deterministic) nodes. PyMc, Winbugs, Smile are the ones I'm aware of.

Based on the different inference methods used by these software (PyMc and Winbugs use MCMC, Smile uses message passing etc), this extension to graphical models formalism appears to be supported in both exact and approximate methods.

I have failed to find any resources that explains how deterministic nodes are processed while fitting models, especially with MCMC methods. Where can I find a good explanation of how deterministic nodes are processed during sampling? There are many resources that explain step by step how sampling algorithms work, but I am yet to see something that covers deterministic nodes

Comment: What is the difficulty? If you have sampled points from one distribution, just apply the deterministic function to each of them to obtain a sample from the distribution of the transformed r.v.

Comment: @overrider Under which conditions that transformation would be a valid 'node' in the model? How should the MCMC algorithm treat it? In PyMc, it is just a method that returns the results of a transformation, but I can't see how PyMc's support for deterministic nodes is related to MCMC algorithm at the abstract, mathematical level. There must be a name for this software feature in the MCMC literature, but I can neither find that name nor resources that discuss its aspects.